# turtlebot3 schematic

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I went thru documenation on turtlebot3 but actually I missed the overall schematics (connection diagram) for electronics. Please canyou point where can I find schematics of turtbot3 connections?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261147/turtlebot3-schematic/) by [peter_cz](https://answers.ros.org/users/26887/peter_cz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @peter_cz

You can find it at the link below.

http://turtlebot3.robotis.com/en/latest/appendix_opencr.html#open-source-hardware

All details of the OpenCR board that are necessary for the users who want to make it by themselves, including the Schematics, the PCB Gerber, the BOM and the Firmware source are fully opened under the open-source licenses for the user and the ROS community. :)

---

Originally posted by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) with karma: 358 on 2017-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0